# Getting `Galleria is not defined` exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I haven't used that plugin before. What I'm getting now is:

**Included scripts**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm referencing `galleria` theme inside a `head` tag. And I've checked up the visibility of either `JQuery` and `Galleria` scripts using `Chrome web developer tools` (and simply calling  `$("body").text("jQuery works");` to assure myself `Jquery` works).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // $("body").text("jQuery works");
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#gallery").galleria({
                width: 750,
                height: 300,
                clicknext: true
            });
        } // function() {
    );  // $(document).ready(
</script>
```

**CSHTML**

```
<fieldset>
    @* other things*@
    @if(Model.AttachedInformation.Count > 0)
    {
        <div id="gallery">
            @foreach(var path in Model.AttachedInformation)
            {
                <img src="@path" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            }
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

*`Two moment are unclear for now`*: can I keep the `div` which is then styled for recognizing by `gelleria` inside a `fieldset`; `Chrome`'s giving me the message that `Galleria is not defined`.

Need an advice!
Thanks!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: It suggests that the galleria javascript file is not being included.  Are you sure that the url is correct for it?  Open the head in the element explorer and click the url to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only reference a Galleria theme.  You also need to reference (and download, if you haven't already) the Galleria core.  http://galleria.io/download/

Make sure you reference Galleria before the theme script.